# How to evenly distribute vertices in an uv map?

Tags: uv, transforms

I try to make a UV map for my object that fits the form of an already existing UV map. I manually positioning the outer edge of the map so it matches the existing map. But the innards are not in good shape.
Now I want to select one of the loops and make the vertices have all the same space between them. I tried to use Looptools but they are not available in UV Image Editor.

**How can it be done automatically to even out the spacing of all the inner vertices on a selected loop?**
[image: vertices of the UV map to evenly distribute]

Comment: It isn't smoothing the loop along the loop, its smoothing laterally with respect to neighboring loops. I want to evenly space vertexes along the loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the loop and enable the Sculpt tool:

[image]

With holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> smooth the selected vertices. This will space them evenly:

Make sure the sculpt brush has Lock Borders enabled:

[image]

Comment: Works fine, thanks. Is it possible to smooth them just along a specific loop when using a bigger sized brush?

Comment: It will smooth only the selected loop. So the selected will be the specific one and then you can use big brush on it. If you want to smooth multiple loops in only one direction then no, the brush is all-directional.

Comment: That helps to know. I tried to select every nth loop and took a bigger brush to get them evenly spaced in much shorter time than doing every line manually. Thumbs up.

Comment: This is not true, it does affect unselected loop as well :/

Comment: Does it still work with blender 2.8 ?