# Make uv vertices evenly spaced

Tags: uv

This topic has already been raised but the solution doesn't seem to work for me. I need to find a way to make the lines in a uv map evenly spaced.

[image: I want the horizontal lines in the selected UV to be evenly spaced]

There was an addon for blender 2.61 that would distribute the vertices on the horizontal and vertical axis https://developer.blender.org/T29981 but I'm not sure if it would work for 2.74. I read that using the uv sculpt smooth tool should work but nothing happens for me when I use that tool.

Does anyone have advice about how to evenly distribute vertices on the x and y?

Comment: Check the answer to this question and see if it helps you. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/how-to-evenly-distribute-vertices-in-an-uv-map?rq=1

Comment: I couldn't get UV sculpt to work. I wentover the area with smooth but nothing happened. I must be missing something :/ The UV squares addon does the job perfectly though, however I would like to know what I could be doing wrong with uv sculpt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Uv_Squares) is what you want. Its a great addon, I've been using it for ages now. Basically what it does is it converts the selected uv area into an nicely lined up square, or into an evenly spaced grid.